# Couldn't parse hash in ruby rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i got response from

```
get 'auth' {:uname => 'apple',:pword => 'xxx'}
puts response.body
```

as

```
"{\"status\":\"Success\",\"success\":\"User is Authenticated and secret token created.\",\"secret_token\":\"1cLojQkX9kuKwhppMPDaEA\"}"
```

so how can i parse?

1. `response.body['status']` gives "status"
2. `response.body.status` gives undefined method

so how can i get status or token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse it with the JSON.parse function, which parses the JSON into a Ruby hash:

```
response_hsh = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts response_hsh[:status]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like

```
result = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

?

So you can access all your data

```
puts result["status"]
puts result["success"]
puts result["secret_token"]
```